# Ionic Card is not scrollable

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an ionic card. And there is only once card. It is big. But is is not scrollable. When I change the orientation to landscape half of the card will be hidden, and there is no way to scroll it.

```html
<ion-content ng-controller="VideoCController">
<ion-list>
  <div class="inset item-text-wrap">
      <ion-item>
          <h2>{{video.video_title}}</h2>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <div class="video-container">
              <iframe ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(video.yt_id)}}" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <h3>Lenght {{video.yt_length * 1000 | date:'mm:ss'}}</h3>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <p>{{video.description | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
      </ion-item>
  </div>
```

Comment: As far as i see, you are showing video in iframe, which will not be scrollable in ionic. So first use thumbnail of image and when someone click on that, open video in some modal or whatever suits you.

Comment: @mudasserajaz I don't want the frame to scroll, I just want to whole card to scroll, because on small devices the content is being hidden and there is not way to scroll.

Comment: That is what i mean. If you try to scroll out of video div, it will scroll.But video  frame won't let you scroll.

Comment: @mudasserajaz Thank you very much. I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to below to know more about how to make ionic scrollable, i haven't tried it but assuming that's the way to achieve scroll.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/

Let me know if you succeed.

Thanks

Comment: I tried that, but scroll is already true, since the default value it true.

Comment: Hi @lamia, use "direction" and then the direction(s) you want. Can be x, y or xy. It work wonderfully for me.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for general case of **ionic-card scroll** scenario. In Ionic versions below **v4**, we could use,

`<ion-scroll scrollY="true">--content--</ion-scroll>`.

But **IonScroll** is removed in Ionic v4. Therefore we have to use

`<ion-card scrollY="true">--content--</ion-card>`

like this.